# Find a value in a table and report a specific score inside another 2 dimensional table

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table like this:

[image]

The first row is a score. The first column is a value.
And inside the table is how many times the score has the value.

Then I have another table like this:

[image]

Where the the first row and column represent the value (first column of the table above)

My goal is to have a macro able to report the score (1,2,3,4) in the seconde table. It has to report the score that have the maximum number.

For example in the table 1, the value -3,53 has 3 times the score of "1" and 1 time the score of "4". So it should report the score of "1" in the seconde table.

Comment: I tried to start writing something but i am really stuck. Because i dont know how to match the value in the first column (from the 1st table) to the second table, like -0,1 - 0,01 = 0,11 so the value has to past here (B3). I know that i did not post any code usually when i asked i do but in this case i dont know how to start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. I post the code if anyone has the same problem as me:

```
Sub test()
    Dim MyRange As Range, AllRange As Range
    Dim MyRow As Range, i As Long, MyCol As Integer
    Dim MyDicoScores As New Dictionary
    Dim MyDicoCorres As New Dictionary, MyKey As Variant, MyDiff As Integer
        'On determine un dico de score
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Scores")

        Set AllRange = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Resize(.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 2, .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Offset(1)


        Set AllRow = .Range(.Range("A1").Offset(, 1), .Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
            'Dictionnaire de correspondance
        For Each MyRange In AllRow.Cells
            If Not MyDicoCorres.Exists(MyRange.Column) Then
                MyDicoCorres.Add MyRange.Column, MyRange.Value
            End If
        Next MyRange
        For Each MyRange In AllRange.Columns(1).Cells
            MyValue = 0
            For i = 1 To MyDicoCorres.Count
                If Not (MyRange.Offset(, i).Value = "") And (MyRange.Offset(, i).Value > MyValue) Then
                    MyValue = MyRange.Offset(, i).Value
                    MyCol = MyRange.Offset(, i).Column

                End If
            Next i
            If Not MyDicoScores.Exists(MyRange.Value) Then
                MyDicoScores.Add MyRange.Value, MyDicoCorres(MyCol)
            End If
        Next MyRange

    End With
            'On met les valeurs dans le deuxieme tableau
        For Each MyKey In MyDicoScores.Keys
            i = 0
            If MyKey < 0 Then
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Negatif").UsedRange
                    Set MyRange = .Columns(1).Range("A1")
                    While MyKey <= MyRange.Offset(i).Value
                       i = i + 1
                    Wend
                        'On remonte
                    MyRange.Offset(i - 1, Int(((Abs(MyKey - MyRange.Offset(i - 1).Value)) * 100)) + 1).Value = MyDicoScores(MyKey)
                End With
            Else
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Positive").UsedRange
                    Set MyRange = .Columns(1).Range("A1")
                    While MyKey >= MyRange.Offset(i).Value
                       i = i + 1
                    Wend
                    MyRange.Offset(i - 1, Int(((Abs(MyKey - MyRange.Offset(i - 1).Value)) * 100)) + 1).Value = MyDicoScores(MyKey)
                End With
            End If
        Next MyKey
End Sub
```